# How to transfer Wordpress files from localhost to azure

Tags: php, wordpress, azure

I have completed my wordpress site in localhost,And i have wordpress domain in azure(defualt wordpress theme).Now i want to transfer complete all files to azure from localhost.Is it possible?Please help me

Comment: You can use some plugin to transfer if you're newbie and cant do manual upload of files.
1. All in one WP migration
2. Akeeba Backup
3. Updraft Plus
Use it at your own risk. These are just options

Comment: Do you want to transfer files?   or your db contents?

Answer (score 1):

Migration plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) is useful for you. you are able to take migration file from your local setup and upload that migration file in your azure setup.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit straight forward.

Go to Tools → Export:

Clicking the Export All button (if you have a site without plugins installed.)
Selecting all content and clicking the Download Export File button (if you have a site with plugins installed.)
Download specific content only, like posts, pages, or feedback.
Wait for the export to process. Once it’s ready, click the Download button that appears, or check your email for the download link.
You will receive a .zip file to save to your computer with the .xml file inside of it. This file contains your posts, pages, comments, categories, tags, and references to your site’s images.
Larger sites will include more than one XML file to ensure that your export process will be fast and complete successfully. When importing into another site, you’ll need to unzip the file and import each of the .xml files individually.

Host/create your wordpress on azure and reverse the process above by using import in place of export.

Import your file to the new site. If you’re importing to another WordPress.com site, you can follow the same steps in this guide.

Answer (score 0):

Create a backup of your WordPress files and database

Install wordpress on azure, you can follow this guide (https://wplift.com/wordpress-microsoft-azure)

You need the /wp-content folder and the export file from WordPress on your localhost, you will need a copy of your site content, WordPress has a built-in exporter for this – simply visit “Tools” > “Export” and choose “All Content” and download the Export file.
Then upload your wp-content folder on Azure and import your content by visiting “Tools” > “Import" and upload your export file.